# Unable to instantiate error?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Here is my source code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static String content;
  private static String phone;
  private String number;
  private String message;

  private  BroadcastReceiver receiver =  new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            number = "";
             message = "";
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     

               message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();


            }
            //---display the new SMS message--- 
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SendMe();
    }
    }


};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(); 
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    }


             public void SendMe(){


    PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);  
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, pi, null);

}
}
```

I keep getting this error in the logcat

> 06-28 17:11:23.241: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1311):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.ftt.autospond.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.ftt.autospond.MainActivity

Here is my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
           <receiver android:name="com.ftt.autospond.MainActivity"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your activities are registered in your androidmanefest.xml file

edit: you can't have your receiver be registered in a preexisting class like that in your manifest. If you do it dynamically in your class there is no need to have it in your manifest... pull that receiver out and see if that takes care of it

Comment: I added that already. I posted my manifest in the edit above so you guys can see.. Maybe i have a problem there.

Comment: you can't have your receiver be registered like that in your manifest.  If you do it dynamically in your class there is no need to have it in your manifest...

pull that receiver out and see if that takes care of it

Comment: @Mutmatt That did it! But the only problem is.. Nothing is happening that is suppose to inside the broadcast receiver... When a text is received a toast isnt displayed. Its like it doesnt realize it has received a text.

Comment: `IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);`

That should take care of it

Comment: @Mutmatt did you mean filter.addAction? Becuase it isnt showing setAction

Comment: @theItRanger22 exactly what i meant. I was kinda goin off my memory :P

Comment: @Muttmatt Okay everything works!!! Your awesome man, but the only thing is, the automatic text message in SendText() method in my code isnt sending the text automatically. I dont know what.

Comment: @theITRanger22 this is how i did mine
`sms.sendTextMessage(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), null, smsMessage, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT), 0), null);` 

the only difference i see is in our intent and you could just change that to null

Comment: @theITRanger I also recommend you use `Log.e("TAG", "some text with an identifier so you know where in the code this log is");`

Comment: @Muttmatt Okay so it works if but the it only works when the other person has the application installed. or the activity above.. If not they never get the text..Why is this?

Comment: I couldn't really understand that

Comment: SO if you see i have a method called SendMe that automatically sends a text. But it doesnt work, it only works when the receiving person has this app installed. other than that the receiving person never gets the message.

Comment: That is a whole new question i think here.. we solved the fcs and receiving part

Answer (score 1):

register the receiver after setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: what is "<receiver android:name="com.ftt.autospond.MainActivity">" in your manifest xml. does it exist and if yes then does it extends BroadcastReceiver. If you are not using this receiver please remove the entry from xml, your error should go.